# Asynchronous network programming with async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming, client-server, async-await

For the past few years, I've developed client/server software using the Asynchronous Programming Model and sockets. This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN, although overcomplicated with synchronisation mechanisms such as ManualResetEvents, illustrates the concepts: you use a `BeginXXX()` and `EndXXX()` method pair for the connection and stream operations.

This has the advantage of letting the thread pool assign threads as needed (e.g. when data is received) rather than having a dedicated thread per connection, which doesn't scale.

Someone recently mentioned that this approach can also be achieved using the async/await model introduced in .NET 4.5, thus using Tasks and making the APM unnecessary for this scenario. How is this done?

Comment: *How is this done* Are you asking about implementation detail of async-await?

Comment: I am asking how you can solve the same problem (i.e. implement asynchronous network programming) using the TAP instead of the APM.

Comment: I am afraid not; the answer is too generic and does not address the specific problem of network programming which I asked about. Perhaps you could add that to your answer, in which case it would be fine.

Comment: You should be more specific about which network programming you're referring to.

Comment: If you can specify what is unclear about my question, I will most gladly arrange it accordingly.

Comment: You ask about networking asynchronous apis. Which? Http? Sockets? Disk? What are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The `Task Asynchronous Pattern` and its used keywords `async-await` lets you take use of async I/O (as you said) but in a "cleaner" fashion.

Instead of using `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` methods and passing callbacks between each other, you can simply `await` on an async method which returns an awaitable (A `Task` is an example of one).

For example, lets make an example using `HttpClient`:

```
public async Task DoGetWebRequestAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
}
```

What this will do is once the method hits the `await` keyword, it will yield control back to the calling method, creating a state-machine behind the scenes (which will be in charge of executing the continuation, propagating exceptions, etc..) and resume via an IOCP (IO Completion port, allocated by the ThreadPool) once the IO work is complete.

The TAP also offers a way to turn the old APM pattern into the TAP using [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
byte[] data = null;
data = new byte[fi.Length];

FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                               FileShare.Read, data.Length, true);

//Task<int> returns the number of bytes read
Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
        fs.BeginRead, fs.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, null);
```

**Edit:**

How to use `async` is simple. For example, with `FileStream`:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReadBufferAsync(string path)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                FileShare.Read, data.Length, true);

    // Read some bytes, not all, just for the example.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    return buffer;
}
```

You mark you method `async` so you can use the `await` keyword inside it, and then simply `await` on the method which reads.

Comment: I know how the TAP works; I merely need to know how it is applied to network programming (for example: in the APM, you recursively call BeginRead() to receive data; how is that done using the TAP)?

Comment: Your example is still about file handling (whereas I asked specifically about network programming). Also, you most likely can't use await so easily for reading data, as you'd prevent multiple messages from being processed concurrently.

Comment: @Gigi Why do you assume you can't read multiple messages concurrently? Also, the API itself isn't the issue, its the way you work with `async`. If you have a specific library you'd like to work with, you should say so

Comment: @Gigi BTW - my first example uses `HttpClient`. If that isn't what you want then you neee to explain yourself better.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the old APM supported by the `Socket` class used a special thread pool, the IOCP ("I/O Completion Port") thread pool, and rather than assigning threads "when data is received", actually assigned threads as I/O operations are *initiated*, but in a way that allows a single thread (or small number of threads…e.g. as many as there are cores on the system) to handle a large number of socket objects and operations.

As far as how to use the new `async`/`await` style API, unfortunately the `Socket` class didn't get any direct `async` love. However, all of the wrappers did. The most straight-forward replacement is to use the `NetworkStream` class, and use `ReadAsync()` and `WriteAsync()`, which are awaitable methods.

If you want to still use the `Socket` API (essentially) directly, you'll have to wrap it yourself with an awaitable implementation. IMHO, a very good resource explaining one possible approach for doing this is here: [Awaiting Socket Operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx)